# Creating a ClickOnce certificate from an issuer authority certificate

Tags: visual-studio, certificate, clickonce, pfx

I am trying to create a certificate from my issuer authority certificate that I purchased so that I can use it in a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application.

I have a .pfx file that I know the password to. How do I create a certificate from this file that I can install into my personal certificates so that I can use it to publish this ClickOnce application with?

I have been looking at makecert.exe, but it does not seem to have found the right way to make this certificate.

Edit:
If I selected the issuer certificate manually I will get this error in Visual Studio:

> The selected certificate is not valid for code signing. Choose another certificate file

Which I know makes sense since these certificates aren't for this purpose. The question is: how do I make a certificate from this one that I can use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You have to have a code signing certificate to sign a ClickOnce deployment.